# Query about symmetric key encryption

Tags: ssl, encryption, certificate, encryption-symmetric

We are in the process of setting up AS2 over https. https uses asymmetric key encryption and the certs are signed by a common CA.  AS2 uses symmetric key encryption.

For AS2, it is my understanding that:

1. setting up a self-signed key (and exporting the cert or public key) is sufficient.
2. All I need to do next is pass on the cert to the trading partner
3. there isn't much advantage in getting the AS2 cert signed by a CA
4. if I do get the cert signed by a CA (say VeriSign), the advantage will be that I do not need to send the cert to the trading partner (effectively step 2 is not required)

Let me know if the above is correct.

Comment: You have this back to front. AS2 uses public-key asymmetric encryption. HTTPS uses TSL/SSL, which in turn uses symmetric encryption via a negotiated session key. HTTPS/TLS/SSL certs are usually but not always signed by a CA.

Comment: Hmm so AS2 uses asymmetric encryption. Thats a pretty big blunder on my part. Does it matter whether the AS2 cert is self-signed (in which case we exchange the public key with the partner) or whether its signed by a CA ?

Comment: If it's self-signed you need another reason to trust that it's owned by the entity you're talking to. This usually means that they convey your certificate to you via some secure offline means involving their written signature and letterhead. Otherwise you're having a securely encrypted conversation with ... someone.